# Synchronize two folders using MSBUILD

Tags: msbuild

I wonder how to synchronize two folders including subfolders using MSBuild.

What I like to do is

a) to copy all files from the source folder to the dest folder that are newer 
   or don't exist in the dest folder

and

**b) to remove all files from the dest folder that don't exist (anymore) in the 
   source folder**

a) is pretty easy using the `<Copy>` task but how can I accomplish b) ?

This is my build file so far:

```xml
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" 
    ToolsVersion="4.0" 
    DefaultTargets="Backup">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <SourceFolder>C:\source</SourceFolder>
        <DestFolder>C:\dest</DestFolder>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesToCopy Include="$(SourceFolder)\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Backup">
        <!-- copy all files from the source folder to the dest folder 
            that are newer or don't exist in the dest folder -->
        <Copy 
            SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" 
            DestinationFiles="@(FilesToCopy->'$(DestFolder)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" 
            SkipUnchangedFiles="True" />
        <!-- TODO: remove all files from the dest folder 
            that don't exist in the source folder -->
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the `GetDistinctItems` task from [MSBuild Extension pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/).
The basic idea is to get the distinct items between files from the source and the destination folder.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <SourceFolder>C:\source</SourceFolder>
    <DestFolder>C:\dest</DestFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FilesToCopy Include="$(SourceFolder)\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Backup">
    <!-- copy all files from the source folder to the dest folder 
                  that are newer or don't exist in the dest folder -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" 
          DestinationFiles="@(FilesToCopy->'$(DestFolder)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" 
          SkipUnchangedFiles="True" />

    <!-- Remove all files from the dest folder 
            that don't exist in the source folder -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DestFiles Include="$(DestFolder)\**"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Cannot compare FilesToCopy with DestFiles directly, 
         root folders are different-->
    <ItemGroup>
      <SrcFilesLeave Include="%(FilesToCopy.RecursiveDir)%(FilesToCopy.Filename)%(FilesToCopy.Extension)"/>
      <DestFilesLeave Include="%(DestFiles.RecursiveDir)%(DestFiles.Filename)%(DestFiles.Extension)"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.MsBuildHelper TaskAction="GetDistinctItems" 
                                                   InputItems1="@(SrcFilesLeave)" 
                                                   InputItems2="@(DestFilesLeave)">
      <Output TaskParameter="OutputItems" ItemName="Distinct"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.MsBuildHelper>

    <Message Text="Distinct %(Distinct.Identity)"/>
    <Delete Files="$(DestFolder)\%(Distinct.Identity)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: That works well! I installed the MSBuild-Extensions and added `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" />` to the buildfile

Answer (score 3):

In case someone don't want or can't install the expansion pack

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" 
    ToolsVersion="4.0" 
    DefaultTargets="Backup">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <SourceFolder>C:\source</SourceFolder>
        <DestFolder>C:\dest</DestFolder>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesToCopy Include="$(SourceFolder)\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Backup">
        <!-- copy all files from the source folder to the dest folder 
            that are newer or don't exist in the dest folder -->
        <Copy 
            SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" 
            DestinationFiles="@(FilesToCopy->'$(DestFolder)\%(RecursiveDir)%Filename)%(Extension)')" 
            SkipUnchangedFiles="True">
            <Output TaskParameter="CopiedFiles" ItemName="Copied"/>
         </Copy>
         <ItemGroup>
            <OutdatedFiles Include="$(DestFolder)\**" Exclude="@(Copied)"/>
         </ItemGroup>
         <Delete Files="@(OutdatedFiles)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: I know this is a really old thread, but just some extra information for people finding this solution (I'm sure I found either this one or a very similar one elsewhere).

Be aware that this approach will leave empty directories in the destination folder as the "Delete" task only deletes files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MSDeploy utility within MSBuild to synchronize two folders like this:

```
<Target Name="SynchronyzeFolders">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_MSDeploySrc>contentPath=C:\inetpub\Dir1\</_MSDeploySrc>
    <_MSDeployDest>contentPath=C:\inetpub\Dir2\,computerName='https://$(RemoteComputerName):8172/MSDeploy.axd',userName='$(MSDeployUsername)',password='$(MSDeployPassword)',authtype='$(MSDeployAuth)'</_MSDeployDest>
    <_MSDeployParameters>-verb:$(MSDeployVerb) -source:$(_MSDeploySrc) -dest:$(_MSDeployDest) $(MSDeployAdditionalParams)</_MSDeployParameters>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Exec Command="msdeploy $(_MSDeployParameters)"
        CustomErrorRegularExpression="ERROR"/>
```

Folders could be either on the same or on the different computers. Folder's path can contain local and network path. And so on. You can syncronyze IIS WebSites as well as folders. Just use different MSDeploy providers: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569040(v=ws.10).aspx
Help for Configuring the Web Deployment Handler: http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler